# For what cases will this logic of this code fail?

Tags: c

In a coding site I came across a question which seem to be very easy. But when I implement a solution it gives me wrong answers for the hidden test cases. I tried to find for what cases it failed but I just couldn't get any.
The question goes as follows

Construct an N×M matrix with entries having positive integers such that

- If `M>1`, ith row is strictly increasing from left to right with a fixed common difference di
  for all 1≤i≤N.
- If `N>1`, jth column is strictly increasing from top to bottom with a fixed common difference cj
  for all 1≤j≤M.
- All the common differences should be distinct.
  In the case of multiple answers, find an arrangement that minimizes the maximum element of the
  matrix.

The code with the logic

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int t=0,n=0,m=0,d=0;

    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
        if(n>=m){
            d=2;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
                    printf("%d ",(i+1) + j*d);
                }
                d+=2;
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else{
            d=1;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
                   printf("%d ",(2*i+1) + j*d);
                }
                d+=2;
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample input
3
3 3
1 2
1 1

Sample Output
1 2 3
3 6 9
5 10 15
1 2
1

Simple logic I tried was, check if the rows are more or the columns, whichever is more increment that by even number C.D (from 2,4,6....) and the other in odd number C.D(from 1,3,5...)
For example: for 2X3
The matrix will be
1  3
2  6
3  9

This logic seems to be correct and while discussing with my friends even they say its right. But I get wrong answers while submitting to the hidden cases.
What logic error might have I done? Could you give me a example for which this code will fail?

Comment: I tried storing it in a array and then printing it. I still get 3 out of 5 wrong answers. Same with this case.

Comment: The algorithm is not correct. Consider building a 2 * 5 array
I believe your algorithm would produce  
`1 2 3 4 5 |
3 6 9 10 15`
but what could be better is

`1 2 3 4 5 |
4 6 8 10 12`

I apologize, i cant get the formatting to work properly, but split into two lines

Comment: 'printf("%d ",(i+1) + j*d);' don't do stuff like that.  Use temporary vars for each term so that it's easier to see what is going on when you run your code under a debugger.  Decomplexify your code so that it's absolutely clear what all var values are as you step through.  'clever' code and anything else that is not really simple is the enemy of debugging.  If you cannot debug, you cannot program computers:(

Comment: @SiddSingal Thank you for pointing that out. I was just boxed in on some particular examples and didn't notice this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Perhaps the judge doesn't like the trailing space on each line. You must output exactly what is asked in the problem statement.

Comment: @MartinJames Ok, I will take care of it in the future. Thank you

Comment: Your code does not even output the correct result for the given test case. You have the rows and columns reversed. In the second case it is clear from the answer that `1 2` is `m=rows n=columns`, yet you have `scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);`

Comment: @WeatherVane in the second output, theres 1 row and 2 columns, and, in the test case, it says `1 2`, so isn't `scanf("%d%d",&n,&m)` working properly with n=rows and m=columns? The loops that are printing also have `n` in the outer loop and `m` in the inner loop, so it seems like it would be printed out correctly how it is

Comment: @SiddSingal for case 1 this code outputs `1 3 5` `2 6 10` `3 9 15` which is the wrong answer. It has the rows and columns transposed. It does *actually print* that result.

Comment: @WeatherVane transposing a square matrix should have no bearing on  meeting the requirements stated for the problem as its written in the question - the only requirement is find any arrangement such that the maximal element is minimal... for a lot of competitive programming, the judges can be smarter than just doing a simple equality check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix shown in the question for the 2×3 case is:

```
1 3
2 6
3 9
```

However, a better solution is:

```
1 4
2 6
3 8
```

We see this satisfies the constraints:

- Each row and each column is strictly increasing.
- Each row has a fixed difference: 3, 4, and 5.
- Each column has a fixed difference: 1 and 2.
- All those differences are distinct.

A general solution follows.

Let the matrix be A<sub>*i*, *j*</sub>. It is clear A<sub>0, 0</sub> should be 1. Let A<sub>0, 1</sub>, A<sub>1, 0</sub>, and A<sub>1, 1</sub> be 1+*a*, 1+*b*, and 1+*c*, respectively. Then simple algebra and induction shows that A<sub>*i*, *j*</sub> is 1 + (1−*i*)*ja* + *i*(1−*j*)*b* + *ijc*.

The common difference in column *j* is *b*+*j*(*c*−*a*−*b*), and the common difference is row *i* is *a*+*i*(*c*−*a*−*b*). These form two arithmetic series with the same step size, *c*−*a*−*b*, so they do not intersect only if they either interleave (for example, *c*−*a*−*b* could be 2 and one of *a* or *b* can be odd while the other is even) or one series is entirely less than the other (for example, *c*−*a*−*b* could be 1). We will consider these cases below.

Let *I* and *J* be the maximum subscripts in the array, *m*−1 and *n*−1, respectively. (These are introduced for brevity, as *m*−1 and *n*−1 appear repeatedly below.) The maximum element in the array, A<sub>*I*,*J*</sub>, is 1 + (1−*I*)*Ja* + *I*(1−J)*b* + *IJc* = 1 + *IJ*(*c*−*a*−*b*) + *Ja* + *Ib*. Observe the derivative with respect to *c* is positive, so, once *a* and *b* are chosen, the minimum value for A<sub>*I*,*J*</sub> is obtained by making *c* as small as the constraints allow, hence either *c* = *a*+*b*+1 (for the case when one series is entirely less than the other) or *c* = *a*+*b*+2 (for the case when the series interleave). For the former, A<sub>*I*,*J*</sub> = 1 + *IJ* + *Ja* + *Ib*. For the latter, A<sub>*I*,*J*</sub> = 1 + 2*IJ* + *Ja* + *Ib*. This reveals we also wish to minimize *a* and *b* subject to the constraints.

The smallest *a* and *b* can be is 1 and 2 (in either order). So in the interleaving case, we have either A<sub>*I*,*J*</sub> = 1 + 2*IJ* + *J* + 2*I* or A<sub>*I*,*J*</sub> = 1 + 2*IJ* + 2*J* + *I*. To obtain the lesser of these, we choose *a* = 1, *b* = 2 if *J* < *I* and *a* = 2, *b* = 1 otherwise. Combinging these, the maximum is 1 + 2*IJ* + *I* + *J* + min(*I*, *J*). Restoring *m* and *n* from *I* and *J* and doing a little algebra gives us a maximum of 2*mn* − max(*m*, *n*).

For the non-interleaving case, we could have *a* = 1, the largest row difference (generally *a*+*i*(*c*−*a*−*b*)) of 1+*I*•1 = 1+*I*, so *b* = 2+*I* to start the column differences (generally *b*+*j*(*c*−*a*−*b*)) with *b* + 0(*c*−*a*−*b*) = 2+*I*. Conversely, we could have *b* = 1 and *a* = 2+*J*. Then we have A<sub>*I*,*J*</sub> = 1+ *IJ* + *J* + *I*(2+*I*) or 1 + *IJ* + *J*(2+*J*) + *I*, or, equivalently, *mn*+*m*<sup>2</sup>−*m* or *mn*+*n*<sup>2</sup>−*n*. The former is less when *m* < *n* and vice-versa.

Note than when *m* ≤ *n*, the interleaved case gives us a maximum of 2*mn* − *n* = *mn* + *m*<sup>2</sup> + (*m*−1)(*n*−*m*) − *m*. Since (*m*−1)(*n*−*m*) is non-negative, that is at least as large as *mn*+*m*<sup>2</sup>−*m*, which is the maximum for the non-interleaved case. The analogous result holds for *n* ≤ *m*. Therefore, the interleaved case never has any advantage. The minimum is always obtained with the non-interleaved case with either *a* = 1, *b* = 2+*I* = *m*+1 or *a* = 2+*J* = *n*+1, *b* = 1, according to which of *m* and *n* is smaller.